# contentEditable.focus needs setTimeout to work when contenteditable enabled in a mat menu

Tags: angular, contenteditable, angular-components, angular-changedetection

this is my html:

```html
<span #myspan [contenteditable]="editable">
...
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
  <ng-template matMenuContent>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="setEditiable()">
      <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
      <span i18n>Edit</span>
    </button>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

this is my ts:

```js
setEditable(){
 this.editable = true;
 console.log(this.myspan.nativeElement.contentEditable); //false
 this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
 console.log(this.myspan.nativeElement.contentEditable); //true
 this.myspan.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

This code does not work, however wrapping the `focus()` line in a `setTimeout`, does. Also, if the enable button is not in a `mat-menu`, it also works fine without a need for a setTimeout.

Oh, I am using [@ng-stack/contenteditable](https://github.com/KostyaTretyak/ng-stack/tree/master/projects/contenteditable) to enable contenteditable

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysb2pt

Comment: Which version you are using in ng-stack? is it 1.0.0 or higher? Can you share stackBlitz?

Comment: Creating a stackblitz would be so helpful. And If you are using detectChanges(), I don't see a point of keeping it before `.focus()`. Put change detection after focus

Comment: I'll do a stackblitz in a moment. ChangeDetection is what's supposed to work to notice that editable is now true, and enabling focus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that is that `mat-menu` component restores focus to the triggering button as soon as menu is closed. This means that your focus method has no effect because it is being immediately overrided.

Wrapping focus method in a `setTimeout` solves the problem since now you call focus after focus has been restored.

Another solution is to say Angular mat-menu to not restore focus by using `[matMenuTriggerRestoreFocus]="false"` on trigger:

```
<button mat-icon-button [mat-menu-trigger-for]="appMenu" [matMenuTriggerRestoreFocus]="false"
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9kc1qk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**